# Is there any difference between most specific hypotheses obtained by Candidate Elimination and Find-S methods?

Tags: machine-learning

In terms of machine learning. 
Is there any difference between most **specific hypotheses** obtained by **Candidate Elimination** and **Find-S** methods?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

If there are several maximally specific hypotheses that fit a data set, Find-S will just return one of them, where as C-E will return all of them as part of the specific boundary of the version space.

If there is only 1 maximally specific hypothesis though, there is no difference.

Hope this helps!